# How to get lost data to mysql replication slave

Tags: replication, mysql

I'm having MASTER-SLAVE mysql replication setup.

suddenly slave crashed. And MASTER worked without any problem. Now I started the SLAVE again. And working fine. Data sync happening OK.

But the problem is, the data is not there on SLAVE at the time when slave was down. (new tables and rows of some tables).

I also did

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.xxxxxx', MASTER_LOG_POS=xxxxx
```

with the latest position of master. But lost tables and rows not coming to SLAVE.(row counts are lesser than master on some tables;)

NOTE: Current data syncing is working. But the problem is I can't get lost data.

Is there a way to get those data without restarting master database , without going through the whole process again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it when the slave gets out of sync....

On the master...

```
# mysqldump -u user -p --all_databases --master-data > all_mysql_data.sql
```

Then on the slave...

```
# mysql -u user -p -e 'slave stop;'

# mysql -u user -p < all_mysql_data.sql

# mysql -u user -p -e 'slave start;'

# mysql -u user -p -e 'show slave status\G;'
```

It would be good for you to read up on [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) for your version. Pay close attention to the --all_databases and --master-data options. Very powerful Ju-ju. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I need to remove the existing data (databases) from the slave ? And also I need only two databases not all of It. And also don't we need to set the master position to the slave again ? other wise how the syncing will happen ?

Comment: No need to drop tables, the dump file will include `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS...` The --master-data option will also add a `CHANGE MASTER TO...` line to the dump file. Like I said, read up on it. Then, create a dump file, open it up and look inside.